# Can I install Google.Apis.Auth or Google.Auth.Calendar on Windows 10 IoT core?

Tags: .net, uwp, google-calendar-api, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have written some smart mirror code based on Windows 10 IoT core running on a rasberry pi3. It's all working apart from Google Calender code. I wrote a desktop UWP app that successfully downloads google calendar data. When I tried to port it to the IoT core UWP project I was unable to install the Google api nuget packages. I get the error:

> Error NU1202  Package Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore 1.38.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Package Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore 1.38.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Is this just not supported or there is there something I can change or upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the minversion in the project settings of your UWP project to 16299 (or higher), in order to enable netstandard2.0 libraries.

This of course requires you to run OS build 16299 or higher on Raspberry PI (which I hope you already do).

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is helping :-) Do I install .net core 2.0 to get a reference to netstandard 2.0.0.0? If so, what should I do to get it on the Pi as well?

Comment: Don't need to install anything. Just make sure you set the minversion in your UWP's project settings to 16299 (or higher). I have added a screenshot to my answer for clarity.